# How to get value of object in Arraylist item?

Tags: android, object, arraylist

I have some result of array-list after I display the value through looping like this

```
{First=00157300-SPT R.ALONSO (M) D.GREEN, Fourth=360010.0, Second=10, Third=360000}
```

And I got that result from :

```
for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){
   Log.d("List Result :", String.valueOf(list.get(i)));
}
```

I create that arraylist from :

```
HashMap temp = new HashMap();

temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, valueSpinner);
temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, count);
temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, price);
temp.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, total);

list.add(temp);
```

I create FIRST_COLUMN, SECOND_COLUMN,THIRD_COLUMN and FOURTH_COLUMN from Constant.java :

```
public class Constant {

    public static final String FIRST_COLUMN = "First";
    public static final String SECOND_COLUMN = "Second";
    public static final String THIRD_COLUMN = "Third";
    public static final String FOURTH_COLUMN = "Fourth";

}
```

And I use import to MainActivity.java :

```
import static com.testing.informationsystem.Constant.FIRST_COLUMN;
import static com.testing.informationsystem.Constant.SECOND_COLUMN;
import static com.testing.informationsystem.Constant.THIRD_COLUMN;
import static com.testing.informationsystem.Constant.FOURTH_COLUMN;
```

How can I get just the `00157300-SPT R.ALONSO (M) D.GREEN` and `360010.0` ?

Thank you.

Comment: Where is the code for which this output came?

Comment: Write here your class

Comment: Please show the code which created this list {First=00157300-SPT R.ALONSO (M) D.GREEN, Fourth=360010.0, Second=10, Third=360000}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems as though you're adding a `Map` to the list, so you end up printing the Map's `toString` method. There probably isn't any need to have the Map in a list like that but I'll assume it should be. What you want to do is request the key-value pairs from the map instead of working with the toString method.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
   HashMap temp = list.get(i);
   Log.d("List Result :", "index " + i);
   Log.d("List Result :", "First = " + temp.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
   Log.d("List Result :", "Second = " + temp.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
   Log.d("List Result :", "Third= " + temp.get(THIRD_COLUMN));
   Log.d("List Result :", "Forth= " + temp.get(FOURTH_COLUMN));
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin. But I change temp.get(FIRST_COLUMN) to temp.get(FIRST_COLUMN).toString(). Thank you very much.